# mongodb-java-driver 3.2 cannot mongoexport with runtime

Tags: java, mongodb

so I try to backup mongodb(v3.2) from java(jdk v1.8) and so far I came up that mongo java driver doesn't provide any classes for backuping databases. After wild goose chase the best solution was - doing that from `Runtime`

Here's the code

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
Date date = new Date();
String timeAndDate = dateFormat.format(date);
File file = new File("backups/"+timeAndDate);
file.mkdirs();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mongoexport --db cookbook --collection foos --out /backups/"+ timeAndDate + "/foos.json;");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mongoexport --db cookbook --collection bars --out /backups/"+ timeAndDate + "/bars.json;"); // ignores perhaps
```

But the problem is that it doesn't create the .json files. Where am I wrong. Thank you for suggestions and answers!

Comment: just wondering if timeAndDate string contains forbidden characters

Comment: Yes, spaces are not allowed (or at least not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are making couple of mistakes. But let me first publish as working code and then I'll explain what's wrong with your code.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
Date date = new Date();
String timeAndDate = dateFormat.format(date);

File file = new File("backups/"+timeAndDate);
file.mkdirs();

try {

    String command = "mongoexport --db cookbook --collection foo --out \"backups/"+ timeAndDate + "/foos.json\"";

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    while(reader.ready())
    {
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    }

    System.in.read();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Problem #1**

> DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
>
> For some reason, mongoexport has problem with date format string. As you can see there is space between dd HH. if you keep this format as it is. you'll get following error.

```
error parsing command line options: invalid argument for flag `-o, --out' (expected string): invalid syntax
try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

**Problem #2**

> File file = new File("backups/"+timeAndDate);
> Here you have a forward slash in your path **foos ---out /backups/"** which points to root folder but it's missing in when you are creating folder which holds backup.